# Python pass function name as argument

Tags: python, function, class, parameter-passing

My goal is to write a class that should allow me to determine which method to call ( A1 or A2 ) while creating an object p. C will call B, B will call A.

```
def A1():
    return 'A1_g'
def A2():
    return 'A2_g'

class test:

    def __init__(self, means=None):
        self.means=means

    def A1(self):
        return 'A1'
    def A2(self):
        return 'A2'
    def B(self,A):
        new_string='methodB called '+A()
        print new_string
    def C(self):
        q=self.B(self.means)
        return q

p=test(means=A1)

p.C()
```

I got this output "methodB called A1_g". But I want "methodB called A1"

If I delete the top 2 fn definition, I got "NameError: name 'A1' is not defined". Want to understand how and why to achieve this.

Comment: I am looking for a way to modify method B inside the class, in order to make object p convenience to use? Such as just pass the name of fn A1 (or through a string) to call A or modify A1 name leading/trailing with some __?    I have many fn name to pass in. I had read [How do I pass a method as a parameter in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881615/python-pass-method-as-argument-in-function) and [Python: pass method as argument in function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881615/python-pass-method-as-argument-in-function) before this post, but not get an direct answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to pass the name of `A1` as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> p = test(means=test().A1)
>>> p.C()
methodB called A1
```

Or, more concisely:

```
>>> test(means=test().A1).C()
methodB called A1
```

#### Alternative: passing the method name as a string

If, instead of passing the method itself, we want to pass the *name* of the method as a string, then we need to change method `B` as follows:

```
    def B(self,A):
        method = getattr(self, A)
        new_string='methodB called ' + method()
        print new_string
```

The `getattr` function returns the attribute of `self` that is named by the variable `A`.

Now, this can be run as follows:

```
>>> p = test(means="A1")
>>> p.C()
methodB called A1
```